# Django DateField without year

Tags: python, django, datefield

Is it possible to have a DateField without the year? Or will I have to use a CharField? I am using the admin to edit the models.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide if you are ok with a regular date object on the model (and the DB) and will just customize the form widgets or if you want the data store to have the specific data.

If you only want to have forms display day and month, you need to write a custom widget and hook it up to the form in the ModelAdmin class. Django's documentation has a pretty good introduction to writing [custom fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#howto-custom-model-fields) and [custom widgets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances)

In both cases it's much easier to subclass an existing Model / widget and change the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateField` is a whole date. If you only care about the month and day then use `__month` and `__day` when querying.

Comment: so if I wanted to retrieve a queryset of all the dates after today it would be something like:

<code>
today = datetime.date.today()
Object.object.filter(date__day=today).exclude() ?
</code>
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
data_sorted = sorted(My_Model.objects.all(), key=lambda e: e.myDataField.strftime("%m-%d"))
```